# How to prove $n$ is not prime when $2^k\mod n = 3$ and $n=2k+1$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I assume that Fermats little theorem is involved since it is in the course material. But I'm not sure how te apply it. (maybe its too early for my brain to work)

Comment: $2^{n-1}=2^{2k}=(2^k)^2\mod n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2^k\equiv 3 (mod \,\ n)$$
$$\Rightarrow n\big|2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}-3$$
$$\Rightarrow n\big|\left(2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}-3\right)\left(2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}+3\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow n\big|2^{n-1}-9   \,\ ..................(i)$$

If $n$ was a prime, then by Fermat' Little Theorem,
$$n\big|2^{n-1}-1    \,\ ..................(ii)$$

From $(i)$ and $(ii)$, we get
$$n\big|(2^{n-1}-1)-(2^{n-1}-9)$$
or, $$n\big|8$$

So $n$ must be $2$ in order to be a prime but it is given that $n$ is odd. 
**CONTRADICTION.**

Comment: How come that:$$ n\big|2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}-3$$
$$\Rightarrow n\big|\left(2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}-3\right)\left(2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}+3\right)$$

Comment: You missed out on the dollar sign on both sides. So I cant read the equations well.

Comment: Yeah i am heavily strugling to get it al right :P

Comment: Um actually what I did there was basically: if $n$ divides $a$, then $n$ also divides $ap$ where $p$ is some non-zero number. Is it okay?

Comment: Thats reaaaly logical indeed. Its still early here... Should get a cup of coffee :P

Comment: Nice to help you. BTW if it solved your problem,  you can accept my answer...:-)